# Unable to change checkbox state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react, redux project and on this particular page the user can update his/her availability by checking or unchecking a checkbox.

In this example I am pulling from the DB, the users last recorded submission for a Saturday.
I fetch this via redux and then access that state to map out the timeslots.

This all works fine, APART from fact once the boxes are rendered I am unable to change the box status from checked to unchecked and vice versa.

I was wondering if its because the `checked` is linked to redux state?

Nb: the onChange is currently in place but not being used needed so this could be change if needed.

```
const [availableTimeTrue, setAvailableTimeTrue] = useState([]) //not in use

const insAvail = useSelector((state) => state.instructorAvailabilityGet)
const { loading, error, availability } = insAvail
const availableTimeAll = availability ? availability.availAll : []
const {
    availSun,
    availMon,
    availTues,
    availWed,
    availThurs,
    availFri,
    availSat,
} = availability ? availability : []


<Form>
    {availSat.map((time) => (
        <Form.Check
            type='checkbox'
            checked={time.status}
            key={time.uuid}
            name={
            moment(selectedWeekDays[0]).format('DDMMMYY') + '_' + String(time)}
            label={time.timeslot}
            onChange={(e) => setAvailableTimes(e.target.name)} //not in use
            />
    ))}
<Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
Submit
</Button>
</Form>
```

any guidance appreciated

Comment: "I was wondering if its because the checked is linked to redux state?" yes

Comment: mmm any ideas on how to work around this? thinking out loud I could probably circumvent redux and just fetch the data directly from DB and render the result

Comment: well it comes down what the "right" state for the checkbox is. What do you want it to show? the state of the DB, or the interactive state of whatever the user just did to it? Usually in react it's the former, in which case you just need to make sure that `time.status` is updated correctly from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [controlled-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [uncontrolled-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Most of the time you should be using `controlled-components`, which is what you're doing now. In this case you should update the respective state value when user interacts with the component, and React will re-render it with updated state.

In this particular example, `setAvailableTimes` should update `time.status`

Comment: thanks, state would have an array of many, in this case I assume i have to be more explicit with what part of the state i.e what part of the array i want to update?

Comment: Yes you need to find the object being updated (using `e.target.name` for example) from the array and update that specific one in your reducer/state handling mechanism